# VALARM not working in Outlook & Android

Tags: android, outlook, icalendar

I have a major problem getting alarms in .ics-Files working with Outlook and Android.

When importing the .ics-File into Sunbird oder Google Calendar, the events are shown right and the alarms are working. 
When importing into Outlook or Android, the events are allright but the alarms will not be imported.

This is my File:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:libical; http://www.nabber.org/projects/ical/
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:Termine
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120628T140417Z
DESCRIPTION:Event 1
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120629T070000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120628T140417
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120629T060000
LAST-MODIFIED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120628T140417
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Event 1
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT780M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120628T140417Z
DESCRIPTION:Event 2
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120727T070000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120628T140417
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120727T060000
LAST-MODIFIED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120628T140417
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Event 2
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT780M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Does anybody have an idea how to get alarms working in outlook an android?

Thank's a lot...

CU - Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have the alarm set to -780 minutes, I could see that that's an issue. Perhaps try -13 hours instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the end-of-line being used is `\r\n`, not just `\n` as is incorrectly shown in many examples on the web.

For more detail see my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16540934/834431

Answer (score 0):

After importing your ICS file, try to set the alarm and export the appointment as an ICS file. You can then compare the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file you want to import.
From .ics to .vcs