# iCalendar alarms

Tags: iphone, alarm, icalendar

Been reading in the [iCalendar VALARM spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.6.6) for a while and just not quite sure how I should do it. I'm trying to generate an ical file with events.

I'm planning to subscribe to this file on my iPhone and I want the iPhone to alert me when there is 1 hour left until the event starts.

Anyone able to help me out with how to do this? Probably rather simple, but I've read myself blind on that spec at the moment :(

Answer (score 2):

a simple example and some pitfalls when expecting cross platform compliance are available [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10259358/1167333)

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion:

1. Create an event (on your computer) with exactly what you need.
2. Export the event
3. Open in an editor

This should give you a solid idea.