# ics alarm not alarming

Tags: icalendar, alarm

I'm trying to implement alarms(`VALARM`) in an .ics file. The idea is that whenever a specified record is created in a system, an automatic email with an invite is sent. The event works fine, it is being sent and I'm able to add it to calendar(both Google Calendar and iPhone/Mac calendar).

The problem that I'm facing now is that I can't add an alarm to it. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10259358/1047258) and also tried parsing my .ics file on the [link](http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/), provided in the answer, but no errors were found. One of the comments also states the following:

> Both Outlook 2013 and Google seem to ignore VALARM regardless of EOL

But this has been posted in May 2014(almost 3 years ago). I can not believe that this is still the case.

I also went through [this documentation](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/valarm.html) and did not find any problems with my .ics file.

So the question is: **do Google and Apple ignore these VALARM components or am I doing something wrong?**

And do I understand correctly that this alarm with action `DISPLAY` should just show me a pop-up in the browser(google calendar) and calendar app?

Body of my file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20170419T091500Z
DTEND:20170419T102500Z
DTSTAMP:20170418T091329Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Me Myself and I:MAILTO:myemail@example.com
UID:00U5E000001JfN7UAK
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=
 TRUE;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:myemail+attendee@example.com
DESCRIPTION:some HTML in here
LOCATION:here
SEQUENCE:3
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test reminder2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:testing reminders n stuff
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20170418T110500Z
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

For info:

- I'm from Europe and timezone here is CEST(+2 from UTC)
- Yes, this alarm was set to alert me in the future(I added this event 2017-04-18 at 13:00 to my calendar and the alarm trigger was supposed to fire at 13:05(+2 from 11:05 as seen in the code))
- I'm creating this file(blob) with `\r\n` in the code

**EDIT**

Tried this also in my hotmail account, no reminder either

Answer (score 3):

Gave an answer here: [Sent email with iCal to outlook with valarm reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256584/sent-email-with-ical-to-outlook-with-valarm-reminder/33268200#33268200)

> Most calendar clients will ignore any alarm that is sent along with an invitation. When you think about it, this makes sense: if you invite me, I may want to accept or decline, but you should not dictate when I want to be notified. On the other hand, when importing, you are making those events your own.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you have any official documentation about it?

Comment: No. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5546#section-3.2.2 allows VALARM in REQUEST. As far as individual product documentation, I really doubt they get into this level of detail.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I found my problem with Outlook.

According to [MSDN Outlook documentation of triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624646(v=exchg.80).aspx):

> On import, Outlook ignores **TRIGGER** properties of type **DATE-TIME**.

So I changed the `TRIGGER` from `DATE-TIME` to `-PT` and it seems to work now.

Edited part of `VALARM` component:

```
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT30M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Alarm test
END:VALARM
```