# .ics File: VALARM for an allday event dosen´t work

Tags: icalendar

I need an ICS-File for a allday event which includes a reminder, one day before the event takes plays.
The ICS-File generates the event without any problem. But the reminder is always set on 18hours, even if the trigger is set on e.g. "-PT15M"....

Can anybody help?

ICS Testfile:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:Karabulut
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:Planing
DTSTART; VALUE=DATE:20200129
SUMMARY: Revenue 
METHOD:PUBLISH
CLASS:PUBILC
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1D
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
END:VALARM
END:VCALENDAR
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the expected behaviour by the receiving application.  The 18 hours may be the default set by you or the application.

Many applications do ot let ics files create alarms.   I know I would not want the ics file to be creating alarms & notifications for me!

See also
[Ical VALARM not registrering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259358/ical-valarm-not-registrering) and
[Sent email with iCal to outlook with valarm reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256584/sent-email-with-ical-to-outlook-with-valarm-reminder)  and the links in the answers.

The RFC5545 specification See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-75 says:
Note: Implementations should carefully consider whether they
accept alarm components from untrusted sources, e.g., when
importing calendar objects from external sources.  One
reasonable policy is to always ignore alarm components that the
calendar user has not set herself, or at least ask for
confirmation in such a case.